# Nexus 7 (2012) soft bricked not recognized by OS

Tags: fastboot, nexus-7, unbricking

I'm going to say in advance that I'm no expert in this subject, so any help is well appreciated...

I have a Nexus 7 (2012) that I had rooted to install Cyanogen Mod in the past. Long story short: The device wasn't working well with CMod, I tried to flash stock again through TWRP but the rom was corrupted and now I'm stucked in a bootloop. I believe it is soft bricked but:

- The device doesn't show up/mount on Win10/Linux even after installing drivers, changing usb ports or cables etc.
- Adb or fastboot doesn't show any devices
- USBDeview doesn't show my device

If anybody in here can help, I'll be forever grateful.

Comment: Download [factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/images#nakasi). Power down device, hold volume up+down + power. That should get you booted to fastboot (bootloader) and flash factory image with fastboot. A [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1907796) with full instructions

Comment: @Josue Riveira Have you read that fastboot doesn't show the device? Because if it's a common flash procedure it won't work

Comment: @ThiagoM It means you have not setup fastboot properly.. Or you're missing something, like for example, some devices require you to specify the vendorId in the fastboot command itself, like `fastboot -i vendorId flash blah bomb`. Check your [XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7) for proper guides

Comment: @GokulNC As I said before, fastboot command does not work. I've tried again just for sure, the only thing I get is `<waiting for any device>`, for ever.